# AngularJS Model Location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm writing a simple AngularJS example that doesn't have a controller. It just uses the default global controller/model.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app=>
  <body>
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" placeholder="first name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName" placeholder="last name">
    <br />
    <h2 ng-style=style>Welcome {{firstName + ' ' + lastName}}</h2>
    <button ng-disabled="!(firstName.length && lastName.length)">Sign Up</button>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where are the `firstName` and `lastName` values stored? This form works as expected so the two-way binding is working. I've tried looking through the `window` object and I didn't see anything in there that might be the global Angular controller. If I wanted to submit these values, where would the "handle" to them be in this example?

**UPDATE**

As I said, this is working as evidenced by [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqpjtsf2/). The name is computed correctly and the button is only enabled once both `firstName` and `lastName` have values. I also tried using Batarang and it did not help. It told me that there wasn't a scope defined yet the application still functions.

Comment: It is `$rootScope`, just place a watch on `$rootScope.firstName` you will see it getting updated. See the console here http://plnkr.co/edit/dVDb3G?p=preview

Comment: Sounds like you're asking the very interesting question: "If I create an app without module name, where is the scope stored?". I don't know. `angular.bootstrap().get('$rootScope')` Gets us a scope, but the value is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Batarang and inspecting for yourself, though I believe those two values would be applied to `$rootScope`

Answer (score 0):

You can view your scope using [ng-inspector](http://ng-inspector.org/). It may not work in js-fiddle, because they do things with iframes that hide the global variables the inspector depends on.

I tried it on a test application with an unnamed module, as in your example, and it discovers the scope as `$rootScope 002`

Because of this I theorized, and have found through experiment, that the scope of an application without a declared module name (and probably with one, too) is attached to whatever DOM node the `ng-app` directive is on.

So, if you put `ng-app` on the `html` tag, this would get you your scope:

```
angular.element(
  document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]
).scope();
```

Using JSFiddle will complicate this testing, since it does iFrame stuff and has multiple html and body tags. Try it in an isolated environment and it's pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

In console, select the result frame, and type:

```
angular.element($('body')).scope().firstName
```

You should see the firstName value. With regards to "If I wanted to submit these values" part, I believe you want to do an ajax call with these values. The best place to do that is by attaching a controller, where you will have direct access to these variables, and then you can use $http service to post to a server.